# How to print a String and then call the same function in the same guard

Tags: haskell

So I am making a function that I want to call, print a string depending on the value (with guards), and then call that same function again with different values.

This is what I was thinking

```
something a
| a <= 1 = "One" && (something (a+1))
| a == 2 = "Two" && something (a+1)
| a >= 3 = "Three" && something (a+1)
| otherwise = something a
```

I know this is an endless loop and I know this is wrong but it's just the idea I had.

Any idea to make this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for debugging only or is the printing actually an essential part of your program behavior?

Comment: Neither... it's just something I wanted to know if was possible or not. No real application for it... yet. Why? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, for debugging purposes you would use functions from [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html), but "They should not be used in production code." so otherwise you'll have to use `IO` properly which is slightly more work.

Comment: You just want to print? Then you need to deal with IO action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the "&&" , instead use the "++". Try this:

```
something :: Integer -> String
something a | a <= 1 = "One" ++ something (a+1)
            | a == 2 = "Two" ++ something (a+1)
            | a >= 3 = "Three" ++ something (a+1)
            | otherwise = something a

main = do 
   putStrLn "Result:"  
   print (something 1)
```